# printf zero padding difference between %g and %f

Tags: c++, printf

I want to understand why zero padding works differently for %g and %f formats in printf. Here's a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  double d = 0.10000000000001;
  printf("%04.2f\n", d);
  printf("%04.2g\n", d);
  return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
0.10
00.1
```

This is reproducible in both VC++ on Windows and gcc on Linux.

Why it works like this? It is a correct behavior?

UPDATE: I found the answer but I think I'll left the question open...

Comment: " I found the answer but I think I'll left the question open..." Well then it would be kind of nice if you shared the answer for others who may come across the same issue.

Comment: Right but I'll do it a bit later. I want to leave a chance for those who are curious to answer and get accepted. Just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. According to the specification of style `g` in C99 7.19.6.1/8:

> unless the # flag is used, **any trailing zeros are removed** from the fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character is removed if there is no fractional portion remaining

while style `f` does not specify that trailing zeros are removed.

Comment: Right, trailing zeroes are removed and thus there's now space to pad with zeroes on the left side. The MSDN also says that "Trailing zeros are truncated".

Answer (score 1):

When using %g, printf chooses the format which gives the best precision in minimum place. You can guess how it evaluates the precision, knowing that for d = 0.10500000 it prints "00.1" while for d =  0.10500001 it prints "0.11".

Answer (score 0):

You can control width and precision by namesake member functions on the std::cout object.

From doc at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream
 precision
    manages decimal precision of floating point operations
(public member function of std::ios_base)
width
    manages field width
(public member function of std::ios_base)